# How to do login validation from MySQL in php?

Tags: php, mysql

**Statement**

I would like to do a simple login validation where the condition is the username and password match to a table in MySQL server called `admin`

**What I have tried so far**

From the following code, there are undefined indexes in `login_check.php`

`$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username'] );`

and `$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password'] );`

**login.php** (front.php = main page)

```
<form method="post" action="login_check.php">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $uname_error; ?></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $pass_error; ?></span>
        <button type="submit" name="Log In" value="Log In">Log In</button> <!--Go to front.php if both username and password are correct.-->
</form>
```

**login_check.php**

```
<?php

    //Establish connection
    include 'connection.php';

    $uname_error = $pass_error ="";

    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username'] );
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password'] );
    $sql = "SELECT admin_username,admin_password FROM admins";

    if(isset($_POST['Log In']))
    {
         //Check Username
         if($uname == "username")
         {
                   //Check Password
                   if($pass == "password")
                   {
                   header("location:front.php"); //If username & password are correct -> log in to front.php.
                   }
                   else //$pass != "password"
                   {
                       $pass_error = "Invalid Password.";
                   }
         }
         else //$uname != "username"
         {
              $uname_error = "Invalid Username.";
         }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

EDIT 1 : `login.php` has been fixed.

Comment: your form is posting to `front.php`, not `login_check.php` you include `login_check.php` before the form has been posted so those values wont be set. you need to reaccesses the structure here

Comment: ^ dont do that or what you have, never store plain text passwords

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240307/5463213

Comment: password with php https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php

Comment: It is just a simple one. So I would like to make able to work first before go for password hashing.

Comment: Your SELECT statement needs a WHERE clause.  Without a WHERE clause the SELECT will return all users from the database.  And you don't seem to execute the query.

Comment: your query is just in a variable, you never called mysqli_query. I have updated login procedure you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Your form's action is `front.php` and the validation code lies in `log_check.php`.

The validation code will not execute because, after submit, the form will redirect to `front.php`.

You can (redirect) set form's action `login_check.php` and the validations will apply.

Also, redirection will work smoothly.

So, concluding 2 changes:

1) Remove/comment `<?php require 'login_check.php'; ?>`

2) Change form action From

`<form method="post" action="front.php">`

To

`<form method="post" action="login_check.php">`

Comment: I have already fixed `login.php` but I think that there are could be some syntax errors in the if-else conditions or MySQL statement in `login_check.php`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should store the password as **Hash**, not in plain text.

I also recommend to use PDO and prepared statments, but this is up to you.

```php
// File: login_check.php

//Establish connection
// include 'connection.php'; 
// PDO Connection String
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');

$uname_error = $pass_error ="";    

if(isset($_POST['Log In']))
{
    // Prepares the SQL Statment
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT admin_username, admin_password FROM admins WHERE admin_username = :username');
    // Fils the named parameter with the username and executes the query
    $stmt = $query->execute(['username' => $_POST['username']]);
    // Fetches the result
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    // Check if the DB has a entry with this username and check if the password matches with the Password Hash
    if($result !== false && password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['admin_password']))
    {
        header("location:front.php"); //If username & password are correct -> log in to front.php.
    else
    {
        $pass_error = "Invalid Username or Password.";
    }
}
```

Create a Hashed password in PHP

```php
<?php
// Create Password with php default Hashing Algo (bcrypt)
$password = password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML -

```
<?php require 'login_check.php'; ?>
<form method="post" action="front.php">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="username" placeholder="Username" style="font-size: 24px" required>
        <span class="error"><?= $uname_error ?></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="password" placeholder="Password" style="font-size: 24px" required>
        <span class="error"><?= $pass_error ?></span>
        <button type="submit" name="Log In" value="Log In">Log In</button> <!--Go to front.php if both username and password are correct.-->
</form>
```

form action is `front.php` which should be `login_check.php` also there is no use of `<?php require 'login_check.php'; ?>` so you can remove that.
you coded very basic login code I think at least you should encrypt the password also, improve your login query.

```
$error = '';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, admin_password FROM admins WHERE admin_username = '$uname'");
list($id,$password) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
    if($password == $pass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        header("location:front.php");
    }else{
        $error = "Invalid Password.";
    }
}else{
    $error = "username does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to check username and password with database, you've never did it. your sql query has never been executed. Although storing plain text password is wrong; but in case of using that, your login_check.php must be something like this:

```
//Establish connection
include 'connection.php';

$uname_error = $pass_error ="";

$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username'] );
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password'] );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE admin_username = '$uname' AND admin_password = '$pass'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header("location:front.php");
} else {
    die('the combination is wrong');
}
```